# Caffe and SSD installation on Ubuntu ,how to know if installed?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, object-detection

Ok so i installed caffe successfully
and when i enter python :

```
python3
import caffe
```

It is imported successfully but is that mean i have the Single shot detector or It is something different , i have been searching for the the whole 7 previous days ?

Comment: What is single shot detector exactly?

Comment: It is method for detecting objects in images using a single deep neural network @Vinny

Answer (score 1):

SSD has it's own Caffe repo for now - https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd , so in case you cloned any other repository, including BVLC's one, you won't have SSD layers (namely "Permute", "PriorBox" and "DetectionOutput" in case of inference only, + "MultiBoxLoss", "DetectionEvaluate" and some changes in "WindowDataLayer" if you want to train), unless of course you took SSD fork.

You can check for these layers existence under src/caffe/layers, or if you have a ready SSD prototxt (for example - train / test / deploy from [here](https://github.com/intel/caffe/tree/master/models/intel_optimized_models/ssd/VGGNet/coco/SSD_300x300)) and try to run it either through caffe tool directly of with Python:

```
import caffe  
ssd_net = caffe.Net('ssd_deploy.prototxt', caffe.TEST) # or caffe.TRAIN  
ssd_net.forward()
```

If this passes, you have SSD support.  If it fails on unknown layers error, you should merge your caffe with the original SSD repo (or just clone it)